# Automatically create firebase record from RSS feeds - feedthefire

Tags: ios, firebase, rss

I am working on a RSS based mobile app. However, all of the posts need to come from Firebase because there is metadata associated with them (likes etc..).

Originally I was thinking of using FeedKit (a RSS library for iOS) so that in the background every time a user is using the app, I'll push any new RSS items to Firebase. This seems like a very inelegant solution however.

I've been looking around for other ways to automate this on the web. One solution is to use Zapier: https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/3282/add-new-rss-by-zapier-feed-items-to-firebase-as-new-records/.

But with the amount of authors in our app this would be way too expensive.

Then I came across a library called FeedTheFire: https://github.com/katowulf/feedthefire

I would love to use this, it seems like a perfect solution. However I only have experience with Swift & iOS development, and have no idea how I would go about implementing this library.

If someone could give me a high-level idea of what would be involved with setting this up, that would be amazing. Keep in mind I have never worked in any other language than Swift, except basic front end web.

I'm not looking for anything specific, I'm sure I can hack up a solution. I just need a better idea of what that solution would actually look like.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  If you need a backend, look into Cloud Functions for Firebase. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: ;If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.